# How to format x axis in matplotlib when plotting pandas series with timestamp as index?

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp, format, axis-labels

I have a pandas Series with two columns, Index (of timestamps) and floats

[image: screenshot of Series]

which I try to plot using Matplotlib as follows

```
s2.plot()
```

which gives me the following plot

[image]

now I want to format the x-axis to just show the timestamp in '%Y-%m-%d' format 
so I try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xdfmt)
ax.xaxis_date()
s2.plot()
```

which fails as follows

> dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
>
> ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

How should I format the x-axis to display legible x-axis labels?

Comment: You need to use `plot_date()`. [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date.html)

Comment: If you want to format dates, the data needs to be dates first, not strings.

Comment: Also, rather than the screenshot, it is always a good idea to show/paste the data so that one can copy and reproduce the results that you are getting. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details.

Comment: @HarvIpan matplotlib's `plot_date` is essentially the same as matplotlib's `plot` if the input are datetime objects. Here the OP uses the `plot` method of pandas, which is a bit different. There are however enough questions around showing how to plot dates with either pandas or matplotlib.

Comment: You are right. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I jumped the guns to comment, I guess.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I had looked at the duplicate to which you linked but the `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d\n\n%a'))` threw an error of ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.

Comment: As said you first need to convert your strings to dates for the dateformatter to be able to format them. As states above, you can of course provide a [mcve] of the issue which allows to see at which exact point your code fails.